# Length of interval is sum of lengths of disjoint subintervals

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

We will call any of the following an interval:

- $(a,b)$
- $(a,b]$
- $[a,b)$
- $[a,b]$

where $a \leq b$.

Let the length of any of the above be $b-a$. Denote the length of an interval $I$ by $\ell(I)$.

Let $I$ be an interval. Suppose we express $I$ as a countable disjoint union of intervals $I_{n}$:
$$ I = \coprod_{i=1}^{\infty} I_{i}.$$

How does one show that
$$\ell(I) = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \ell(I_{i})?$$

Comment: Yes, this is true.

Comment: Can you prove it? I edited my question to reflect the fact that I am looking for a proof. Thanks!

Comment: Your measure is determined by your definition of the length of an interval. And the countable additivity of the measure yields the answer to your question. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measure_(mathematics)#Definition

Comment: @MundronSchmidt I suppose so, but it seems to me that there should be an elementary proof, i.e. one which doesn't reference the lebesgue measure.

Comment: The problem is, that you define $\ell$ just for intervals. To consider what $\ell(I)$ for a union of intervals can be, you have to extend your definition of $\ell$. You could extend $\ell$ to the Borel-Algebra on $\mathbb{R}$ and you get then the Borel measure. But your setting isn't enough yet.

Comment: But I am only interested in the case where $I$ is already an interval.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh I think this doesn't work; consider the cover of the interval $I=(0,1]$ by intervals $(1/(n+1), 1/n]$, $n=1$, $2$, etc. There is no first interval here

Comment: Yeah I got it and that's why deleted my comment. I guess you will have to define some measure for the union of intervals and develop some properties of that measure. Then you can establish your claim. Thus the result you seek is not entirely trivial (although it may appear a bit obvious) and does need some development of ideas of a measure function.